# How to usually .htaccess file when it is hidden in ftp

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, drupal-6

I usually cannot see .htaccess file because it is hidden, when I login to remote servers with ftp access.

Since I don't have shell access, I usually perform the following steps to edit the file:

I change the settings on my mac (from terminal) to see invisible files
I open .htaccess file on a standard drupal installation and I edit it
I upload it to the remote server and I overwrite the existent one
I disable hidden files on my mac

I was wondering if there is a faster solution

thanks

Comment: Probably should be asked on Superuser. But I will say if you know the .htaccess file is in a particular directory but can't see it then why not just open up terminal application and use some editor like vi or pico to open file and make changes. Then just save once you are done. Seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have a separate file in my Drupal root called `production.htaccess` or something along those lines. Not only does this expose the file in Finder without revealing every single .DS_Store on my system, it also allows me to set separate .htaccess directives for different environments. Then, I just rename `production.htaccess` to `.htaccess` after I upload it to the server.

More often than not, the two .htaccess files are identical, but even in that case, I still use this method for the sake of convenience.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP application should have the option to show you hidden files; normally, that is an option available on FTP client applications for Mac OS X.